# How to make custom circle progress bar?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I need to make this kind of progress bar in my project. How can I make it work?

The initial state of the progress bar.
[image: The initial state of the progress bar.]

This is when the progress bar fills up.
[image: This is when the progress bar fills up.]